# Mi matriz con números aleatorios se desborda, porque?

Tags: c++

en el código que estoy haciendo tengo que crear una malla cuadrada, rellenarla con números aleatorios en un rango (del 0 al 8) y después mostrar la malla junto con una copia de esta cambiando los números por símbolos con colores,(ej. El 0 se cambia por un cuadrado rojo). Sin embargo aún que el código funciona bien en algunos casos de vez en cuando me salta un error de que se tumbó el núcleo, por lo que vi se debe a que un valor desborda la memoria pero no localizo nada así en el programa y ando perdido.

El error es este:
**Timeout: the monitored command dumped core (un directorio que desconozco) línea 103: (un número que varía entre 10 y 17) segmentation fault timeout**

Si alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal o que desconozco...

Este es todo el código, decir que es fácil de ver si cambias la variable x y ocurre casi siempre con el número 7, en el 11 da el resultado y el error y en otros solo muestra el error, el resultado o a veces cosas sin sentido ninguno:

````
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int aleatorio(){ //funcion para sacar un numero aleatorio completo
    unsigned short int ale;
    ale=(1+rand()%7);
    return ale;
};

int main(){
srand(time(NULL));//usamos el reloj para generar una semilla distinta para los numeros aleatorios cada vez que ejecutemos el programa
unsigned short int x=11;//tamaño de la malla
unsigned short int x1=0;//Variables para contear
unsigned short int x2=0;//
unsigned short int y1=0;//
unsigned short int y2=0;//
unsigned short int ale;// hueco para el numero aleatorio
int malla[x][x];//creamos la malla del tamaño que queremos

for(;x1<x;x1++){//cambiamos la columna para rellenar cada vez que el bucle siguiente acabe hasta que rellenemos la malla
    
    for(;y1<x;y1++){//llenamos la primera fila de la malla con numeros aleatorios
    ale=aleatorio();
    malla[x2][y2]=ale;
    x2++;
    };
    
    aleatorio();
    malla[x2][y2]=ale;
    y1=0;
    y2++;
};

x1=0;//reseteamos los contadores
y1=0;
x2=0;
y2=0;

for(;x1<x;x1++){
    
    for(;y1<x;y1++){
    cout<<malla[x2][y2]<<"";//usamos los mismos bucles para mostrar los numeros de la malla
    x2++;
    };
    cout<<endl;
    y1=0;
    y2++;
};

cout<<endl;

x1=0;//volvemos a resetear los contadores
y1=0;
x2=0;
y2=0;

for(;x1<x;x1++){//traducimos los numeros mostrados antes a colores para verlo mejor y usarlo de resultado final
    
    for(;y1<x;y1++){
        switch(malla[x2][y2]){//definimos los colores por cada numero posible
            case 0:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 1:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 2:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 3:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 4:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 5:
            cout<<"⬛";
                break;
            case 6:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 7:
            cout<<"";
                break;
            case 8:
            cout<<"⬜";
                break;
        }
        x2++;
    };
    cout<<endl;
    y1=0;
    y2++;
};

return 0;
};```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay algunos errores en tu código, el error lo tienes en la forma en que estás implementando tus ciclos `for`

Explicación del problema, cada vez que tu código ejecuta el `for` interno, en la última línea tu incrementas `x2`, suponiendo que tienes una matriz (Malla) de 2x2 y suponiendo que el valor de `y1` es 1 (Segunda iteración), al ejecutar la línea donde incrementas `x2` entonces `x2` obtiene un valor igual a 2, pero tu matriz es de 2x2 por lo que tendría las columnas 0 y 1 y las filas 0 y 1, por lo que el valor 2 ya está fuera de la matriz

```
for(;x1<x;x1++){
    
    for(;y1<x;y1++){
        ale=aleatorio();
        malla[x1][y1]=ale;
        x2++; // <----- El error está aquí
    };
    
    aleatorio();
    malla[x2][y2]=ale; // <----- Aquí accedes a valores de x2 que están fuera de la matriz
    y1=0;
    y2++;
};
```

Ahora, hay otros errores de concepto que al resolverlos pueden mejorar y solucionar tu código

1. En tus ciclos `for` puedes declarar tus contadores para uso interno en el `for`

Por ejemplo

```
for (int x1 = 0; x1 < x; x1++)
```

En este caso `x1` es declarada y utilizada en el ciclo `for`

2. En una matriz de 2 dimensiones, la estructura es `matriz[fila][columna]`
3. En tu código utilizas 2 ciclos `for` para recorrer toda la matriz (Eso es correcto), el problema es que al iterar en la dirección `y` asignas e incrementas `x` es decir, estás recorriendo las filas pero incrementas columnas, para una matriz cuadrada (Mismo número de filas y de columnas) no hay mucho problema, pero si quisieras utilizar otro tipo de matrices entonces ya no funciona

```
for(;x1<x;x1++){//iteración de columnas de acuerdo a tu pregunta
    
    for(;y1<x;y1++){//iteración de filas de acuerdo a tu pregunta
    ale=aleatorio();
    malla[x2][y2]=ale;
    x2++; // incremento de columnas
    };
    
    aleatorio();
    malla[x2][y2]=ale;
    y1=0;
    y2++; // incremento de filas
};
```

4. Utilizas una variable `ale` que podría quitarse ya que solo asignas un valor aleatorio y en la siguiente línea lo asignas a la matriz, puedes asignar directamente el valor aleatorio a la matriz

```
ale=aleatorio();
malla[x2][y2]=ale;
```

5. Utilizas contadores "extra" para rellenar tu matriz, pero podrías utilizar `x1` y `y1` que ya están recorriendo tu matriz para evitar declarar variables extra que podrían ocasionar problemas (Como en este caso que `x2` desborda el tamaño de la matriz)

Podrías "limpiar" el código del el ciclo `for` con los comentarios anteriores y quedaría así (`y1` representa el número de fila y `x1` el número de columna)

```
for (int y1 = 0; y1 < x; y1++) {
    for (int x1 = 0; x1 < x; x1++) {
        malla[x1][y1]=aleatorio();
        cout<<malla[x1][y1]<<" ";  //<-- Puedes mostrar la matriz que creas en el mismo for, no necesitas recorrer la matriz una segunda vez
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Usando la misma estrategia para el segundo ciclo `for` donde vas a cambiar el número por el color y juntando todo el código nos quedaría así:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int aleatorio(){ //funcion para sacar un numero aleatorio completo
    unsigned short int ale;
    ale=(1+rand()%7);
    return ale;
};

int main(){
srand(time(NULL));//usamos el reloj para generar una semilla distinta para los numeros aleatorios cada vez que ejecutemos el programa
unsigned short int x=11;//tamaño de la malla
int malla[x][x];//creamos la malla del tamaño que queremos

for (int y1 = 0; y1 < x; y1++) {
    for (int x1 = 0; x1 < x; x1++) {
        malla[x1][y1]=aleatorio();
        cout<<malla[x1][y1]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;

for (int y1 = 0; y1 < x; y1++) {
    for (int x1 = 0; x1 < x; x1++) {
        switch(malla[x1][y1]){//definimos los colores por cada numero posible
            case 0:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 5:
                cout<<"⬛";
                break;
            case 6:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 7:
                cout<<"";
                break;
            case 8:
                cout<<"⬜";
                break;
        }
        cout<<malla[x1][y1]<<" "; // <-- Comenta esta línea si no deseas mostrar el número encima del color
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
};
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo tendré también en cuenta para la próxima